# Recyclerview onClick returns wrong view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a `RecyclerView` that holds 10 or so views. Each view represents a course, which is stored in an `ArrayList`. Each Course has an enum "State" which controls coloring and ensures that only one course can be selected at a time. This worked perfectly until I unknowingly made a small change, and didn't realize until a day or more later.

Now, clicking on a course will cause the `onClick()` method to receive the wrong view, usually 4 or 5 more to the right. This view won't even necessarily be displayed by the `RecyclerView` at the time of the click, which will mean that the coloring cannot be updated correctly and big problems are caused down the line.

Here's the Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new CoursesAdapter(courseList, context);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.courses_recyclerView);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.setOnCourseClickListener(new CoursesAdapter.OnCourseClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCourseClick(Course course) {
            //TODO when the course is clicked the course will be passed.
            Log.e("TESTING ******", " Course Clicked " + course.name);

            if ( currentCourse!=null) {
                previousSelection = currentCourse;
                previousSelection.setStates(ButtonStates.UNSELECTED);
            }
            currentCourse=course;
            currentCourse.setStates(ButtonStates.SELECTED);

            //refreshCourses();

            //TODO broadcast Course change.
            Intent intent = new Intent(COURSE_SELECTED);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCourseDoubleClick(Course course) {
            //TODO when the course is double clicked the course will be passed.

        }
    });
}
```

The Course passed to the `onClick()` is always wrong. State control is done at the fragment level, since a `RecyclerView` adapter would recycle a "selected" view to a non-selected view at times. Often, `onBindViewHolder()` will not run after a course has been selected, and since the switch statement used to check the states of buttons and update them is done in the adapter, colors are not updated properly.

Here's the adapter:

```
@Override
public holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.course_layout, parent);


    return new holder(new CourseRaceButton(context));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final holder holder, final int position) {

    currentCourse = courses.get(position);

    holder.button.setData(courses.get(position), true);

    if (!initialised) {
         if (position == 0) {
            OnCourseClickListener.onCourseClick(currentCourse);
            selectedCourseView = holder.button;
        }
        initialised = true;
    }

  switch (currentCourse.getStates()) {
        case UNSELECTED:
            holder.button.colourAsDeselected();
            break;
        case SELECTED:

            holder.button.colourAsSelected();
            //selectedCourseView = holder.button;
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return courses.size();
}

public interface OnCourseClickListener {
    void onCourseClick(Course course);

    void onCourseDoubleClick(Course course);
}

public class holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CourseRaceButton button;

    public holder(CourseRaceButton view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        button = view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.e("TESTING ******", " ON TOUCH COURSE ");

        if (OnCourseClickListener != null) {
            OnCourseClickListener.onCourseClick(currentCourse);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

My natural reaction is to put `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the fragment level `onClick()` in order to properly update the colors, but that gives illegalState exception and would never stop the `onClick()` returning the wrong course.

Comment: first avoid enum in andoid development...

Comment: For what reason? Won't be causing this particular problem though

Comment: check this one..https://android.jlelse.eu/android-performance-avoid-using-enum-on-android-326be0794dc3

Comment: Thank you, this looks useful. I will think about changing out from Enum in the future. Any ideas as to why the onClick receives the wrong view though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your `onClick()` method. You shouldn't be passing `currentCourse` as a param, as that variable will be storing the course of the last recycled view(last call to `onBindViewHolder()`), and not the one you clicked upon.

Try this line instead:
`OnCourseClickListener.onCourseClick(courses.get(getAdapterPosition()));`

Comment: Well spotted! Works perfectly now. Wouldn't have thought to try that, since it was working correctly at some point. The currentCourse must have been updated properly at some point and removed later, but this way is much better. Thank you